# PHP Form not directing to correct pages

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, syntax

I'm making a login page for the admins to make some changes to a website easily. However, the login page isn't working correctly. It won't go to the error page **InvalidLogin.html** and it won't go to the next page of the admin website **AdminChanges.php**.

Instead, I'm getting the following message:

**Not Found
The requested URL /website/method="post" was not found on this server.**

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit'] == "submit")
    {
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $passWord = $_POST['password'];

$db= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("onlineform", $db);


$checkUserNameQuery = "SELECT username FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$checkUserName = mysql_query($checkUserNameQuery);
$checkPassWordQuery = "SELECT password FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$checkPassWord = mysql_query($checkPassWordQuery);

if (($userName == $checkUserName) && ($passWord == $checkPassWord)) 
    {
    $AdminChanges = "AdminChanges.php";
    }
else 
    {
    $AdminChanges = "InvalidLogin.html";
    }
}

function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = <?php PrepSQL($AdminChanges); ?>  method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" />
password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post you html generated code

Comment: Have a look at your `<form>` tag. What's the action attribute? Why are you running it through your PrepSQL function?

Comment: I'm running it through PrepSQL because the page it goes through, depends on whether its the right username and password or not. If it's not, the variable will equal the html that tells you its not the right username/password, or it will equal the html that has the next page. PrepSQL removes the magic quotes and inserts new ones

Comment: It $_POST['submit'] if statement doesn't let $AdminChanges be set for the form unless it has already been submitted.

Comment: Since you're assigning a string page name to $AdminChanges, there's no reason to stripslashes (there are none) or run it through mysql_real_escape_string. It's not going into mysql, nor is there anything to escape. You should just be able to echo $AdminChanges as is... with quotes around the php block, of course.  Check the HTML source and you can see what it's really showing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with php form and sql commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576624/error-with-php-form-and-sql-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems are joining forces to cause this error. First, your `PrepSQL` function does not echo the response, and neither does the code that calls it. You need to `echo` or `print` the response so that it appears in your generated HTML.

```
<?php echo PrepSQL($AdminChanges); ?>
```

Second, you need to encapsulate that value of the `action` attribute in double-quotes, like this:

```
<form action = "<?php echo PrepSQL($AdminChanges); ?>"  method="post">
```

Also note that your code assumes that your `mysql_query()` statements were successful. For troubleshooting purposes, you should at least add an `or die(mysql_error())` statement to the end of the `mysql_query()` lines. This will allow your code to provide some feedback when the query fails.

Additionally, please note that your query-handling method will never result in a valid login response.

```
$checkUserName = mysql_query($checkUserNameQuery);
$checkPassWord = mysql_query($checkPassWordQuery);
if (($userName == $checkUserName) && ($passWord == $checkPassWord))
```

`mysql_query()` returns a MySQL resource, not a single field from the database. Your code attempts to compare that resource to the supplied username and password, and the comparison will always fail. For details about handling the results of `mysql_query()` see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/mysql_query).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors I noticed:

Your $_POST['submit'] if statement doesn't let $AdminChanges be set for the form unless it has already been submitted.

To fix this you could change your if submit statement to just redirect to your invalid login page like so:

```
if (($userName == $checkUserName) && ($passWord == $checkPassWord)) 
{
    //Correct info do what you need to here
}
else 
{
    header("Location: InvalidLogin.html");
    exit();
}
```

And also:

You need to change the action to go post to this page.

```
<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: no $AdminChanges haven't been set before, how should I set this?

Comment: yeah still gives me the same problem :/

Comment: ok I figured out that the problem is on line 38, not sure what exactly though

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
    PrepSQL($AdminChanges);

with:
    print PrepSQL($AdminChanges);

Comment: can you view source and paste what your entire <form.. tag looks like once you do this?

Comment: <form action =   method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" />
password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

Comment: Your function is returning  a blank. This is because you're passing in $AdminChange, which is set with local scope within your if(username==checkUsername) block, and so probably has no value when you're calling the function. Just before that "if" statement, put something like this:

$AdminChanges="";

Comment: yeah I've tried that, giving me the same thing. Anything that's not blank, I can set it to?

Comment: beginning or end of the function?

Comment: Ignore previous comment (just deleted). Forget about the form for now. Add this and see if you get any output:
<?php print "[".PrepSQL("Blah.html")."]<br>";

Comment: Also,  "print $AdminChanges" and see if it's even set. I'm guessing not.

Comment: yeah the Blah.html is giving me a blank for form ="" as well, strange. I think there's a problem with PrepSQL

Comment: ok I figured out that the problem is on line 38, not sure what exactly though

Comment: try commenting out the call to mysql_real_escape_string. Gotta go. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action = "<?php echo PrepSQL($AdminChanges); ?>"  method="post">
```

You need to echo the value.

Comment: tried this, with prepsql and without it, using echo. I think echo's the right idea though but still not working

Comment: yeah thats what I meant sorry, I've tried with and without the quotation marks

Comment: <form action =   method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" />
password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

Comment: To be honest, if you are hardcoding the values yourself you don't really need to pass it to the function. Try:  <form action = "<?php echo $AdminChanges; ?>"  method="post">